# django-admin command can't be run because files are not in the right place

Tags: python-3.x, django, pycharm, anaconda, bin

So I thought I installed anaconda and Django correctly but I guess I didn't because my django-admin commands don't work. As you can see here, I have the file paths for a couple Django files all screwed up:

```
/Users/user/anaconda3/bin/django-admin
/Users/user/anaconda3/bin/django-admin.py
/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Django-3.1.5.dist-info/*
/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/*
```

This makes it so I can't run any django-admin commands that I need to run to start a new project in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue--make sure that you install djangorestframework inside the virtual environment you are working in, not the base one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try change the project structure in Pycharm settings

Comment: I was following a tutorial online and it seemed to show that Django-admin is located in user/bin/ folder but I'm not sure if it was just that one, or all the ones I listed above...do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I tried to go into Pycharm preferences but there really isn't any option to change anything related to Django commands. It literally just shows file structure of the project you're in...